# What limit is referred to by the `uploadLimitExceeded` response from the YouTube Data API?

Tags: ruby, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota

I'm working on updating some code I wrote a while back to integrate YouTube with the [Shrine](http://shrinerb.com) ruby file-attachment library using the [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) gem.

In its test suite, I usually stub out all YouTube API communication with recorded HTTP responses and all is well. When adding new features, I run the tests against the live YouTube API which ends up uploading and deleting a tiny blank mp4 many times.

Recently, the YouTube API has been returning 400 errors with:

> uploadLimitExceeded: The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.

This doesn't seem to correlate with the quota limits in the API console for either the user or the app, and I haven't been able to find much documentation around what it might be.

- Does anyone have insight into what limit this error is referring to?
- Is it a rate limit?
- a daily limit?
- a lifetime-of-the-user limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[badRequest (400)  uploadLimitExceeded](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.insert)  The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.

Basically means that the user in question has exceed their upload limit for the day.  The YouTube api has a slightly different quota system then other Google APIs the ones listed in developer console are just the general ones.  You should check [calculating quota usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage)

- 200,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
- 10,000 write operations and 90,000 additional read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
- `400 video uploads, 1500 write operations, and 50,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts`.

Sounds like you uploaded a lot of videos.  This quota should reset at midnight west cost USA time.